# Retain XML version when file is saved in SQL Server database using Python

Tags: python, sql-server, xml, lxml

My Python code pulls locally stored XML file and saves it in a SQL Server database. However, I see that file stored in database is missing the initial XML version statement:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

In order to retain the initial XML version statement, I came across `lxml` documentation which states to add parameter `xml_declaration=True`. Using this parameter, I can see the XML version printed in python console. But, when I try to use the same parameter to store it in the database, I get an error:

> Type: bytes cannot be serialized exception

Can anyone please help me resolve this exception?

Python code:

```
    print("Connecting..")
    # Establish a connection between Python and SQL Server
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                          'Server=TestServer;'
                          'Database=test;'
                          'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    print("DB Connected..")

    # Open the workbook and define the worksheet
    path = 'C:\\Arelle-master\\arelle\\plugin\\TestPlugin\\TestExcel.xlsx'
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    print("Excel Loaded into xlrd..")

    # Get XML File
    XMLFilePath = open('C:\\TestPlugin\\HelloWorld.xml')
    x = etree.parse(XMLFilePath)
    print(etree.tostring(x, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)) # Shows correct version of XML file in console.

    CreateTable = """
    create table test.dbo.StoreInfo
    (
     col1 varchar(100),
     col2 varchar(100),
     col3 varchar(100),
     col4 varchar(100),
     MyXML XML

    )
    """

    # execute create table
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
         cursor.execute(CreateTable)
         conn.commit()
    except pyodbc.ProgrammingError:
        pass
    print("Table Created..")

    InsertQuery = """
    INSERT INTO test.dbo.StoreInfo (
        col1,
        col2,
        col3,
        col4,
        XBRLFile
    ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"""

    # Grab existing row count in the database for validation later
    # cursor.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM test.dbo.StoreInfo")
    # before_import = cursor.fetchone()

    for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
        col1 = sheet.cell(r, 0).value
        col2 = sheet.cell(r, 1).value
        col3 = sheet.cell(r, 2).value
        col4 = sheet.cell(r, 3).value
        col5 = etree.tostring(etree.tostring(x, xml_declaration=True))  # Code throws exception at this line.

        # Assign values from each row
        values = (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)

        # Execute SQL Insert Query
        cursor.execute(InsertQuery, values)
```

Exception:

```
col5 = etree.tostring(etree.tostring(x, xml_declaration=True))  
File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3391, in lxml.etree.tostring
```

> TypeError: Type 'bytes' cannot be serialized.

Any idea how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*MS SQL Server* XML data type doesn't preserve XML declaration prolog. It is stripped out.
If you do need to have it for any reason you would need to change data type to *NVARCHAR(MAX)*.
The XML data type is internally stored as UTF-16 encoding. Even more precise, SQL Server is using *varbinary(max)* data type
internally, but the content itself is UTF-16 encoded text.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. It seems SQL server does not retains XML declaration. Following article was helpful - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms187107(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN